# Generating random 2D lattice: Python appends same row multiple times instead of new row each time

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to randomly generate a 2D 20x20 lattice of 1's and -1's in Python. I am generating 20 different rows, and all seems to be going well up until I actually try to append the generated rows into the big array, `A`. The print function returns 20 different randomly generated rows exactly like I want, but when I add in the append function, it only appends the first generated row into the array twenty times.

It seems like a simple thing, but I am somehow baffled. Can you explain to me why this is, and how I can fix it? Here is my code:

```
from random import randint
# generating the lattice 
A = []
row = [0]*20
def genrow():
    for i in range(0,20):
        p = randint(1,100)
        if p < 50:
            row[i] = 1
        else:
            row[i] = -1
    return row

def newrow():                
    for j in range(0,20):
        genrow()
        print(row)
        A.append(row)

newrow()

print(A)
```

Comment: Is your indentation wrong only in the post or also in the code you are running?
the `if p<50` and anything till return should be indented 8 spaces...

Comment: You say "the first generated row" as if there are multiple rows you're generating, but I only see one line which says `row =`, and then a bunch of commands which modify that single row.  If you clarify which line in your code you think is making a new row, we'll know which question to close this as a duplicate of. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you work with the global `row` and lists are mutable so you append a link to the row but you change this row again and again.

A possible solution would be to copy the row before appending:

```
from random import randint
# generating the lattice 
A = []

def genrow():
    for i in range(0,20):
        p = randint(1,100)
        if p < 50:
            row[i] = 1
        else:
            row[i] = -1
    return row

def newrow():                
    for j in range(0,20):
        genrow()
        #print(row)
        A.append(row.copy()) # Copy it before appending.

newrow()

print(A)
```

An alternative is to create new rows in your function and append these:

```
from random import randint
# generating the lattice 
A = []

def genrow():     
    row = [None] * 20 # Create a new row
    for i in range(0,20):
        row[i] = 1 if randint(1,100) < 50 else -1 # Notice I changed this to make it shorter
    return row

def newrow(): 
    for j in range(0,20):
        row = genrow() # Catch the returned row
        A.append(row) # Append the new row not as copy this time

newrow()
print(A)
```

You could even make it shorter still with list comprehensions:

```
from random import randint
# generating the lattice

def genrow():     
    return [1 if randint(1,100) < 50 else -1 for _ in range(20)]

def newrow(): 
    return [genrow() for _ in range(20)]

A = newrow()
print(A)
```

one could even combine these list comprehensions into one:

```
def newrow(): 
    return [[1 if randint(1,100) < 50 else -1 for _ in range(20)] for _ in range(20)]
```

---

Notice that these are all doing the same thing with different complexities and approaches. The important fact is that you either `copy` or create new lists that you append. All the other stuff is just making it shorter (and probably faster).

Comment: plus 1 for list comprehensions

Comment: well, if you look for brevity instead of explanation of the original code, then numpy will win ... :)

Comment: I think the misunderstanding was just the mutability of lists, what more explanation needs to be there? I just saw the opportunity to provide some alternatives (using arguments and returns) and some further insights (list comprehensions, and one-line ``if ... else ...``) and to illustrate them at this code. Why shouldn't I provide them?

Comment: yes, sure you can; it just may be too much for him to understand, or at least I have to get used to this still. And: with `numpy.random.randint` you are even shorter and easyer to understand (well, not quite *understand* what happens, but believe the syntax matches the output :))

Comment: Yes, numpy is fine but your example isn't doing what the OP wants to do and giving a ``shape`` as ``size`` might be normal for someone regularly working with numpy but it's not "clear". Numpy provides much more overhead than list comprehensions (at least I thinks so). But comparing answers isn't helping either. I think having both of our answers is much better than having only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

A list is a mutable object, so if you have `row_1 = row` and then `row_2 = row`, then, when you change `row_1`, `row_2` will be modified as well.

That's what you do (assuming that the indentation is as I guessed in my comment)

You have a global variable row, that you modify in your function `genrow()` -- modify all the time and overwrite the old results. 
Note, that your function has no input, but *even passing this variable to your function would not help*. Since it stays a single variable, with many different names, inside and outside the function.

You need to generate a new row in your function. That's all!

For further reading, funnily, [this link](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) I got recommendet today, it's what you need to understand (well, if you like; you *need* only to assign the row inside your `genrow()`).

---

Or, for brevity, this is all the code you need:

```
import numpy as np
A = 2 * np.random.randint(0, 2, (20, 20)) - 1
```

that's all... disillusioning, isn't it? :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be ``A = np.random.choice([-1, 1], (20, 20))``?

Comment: oh, you are right, I didn't read the original code carefully enough... I'll edit

Comment: ahh, I feel so silly now. This has all been very insightful. I guess that's why they warned me about global variables...!

Comment: Yes, but this cannot be the only and not the main reason against globals - since 'avoid global variables' normally means, 'pass everything the function needs to it, instead of defining it outside' -- which would not help against this issue, that a list is mutable.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the following pieces of code should be indented in the genrow function definition.

```
row = [0]*20
```

and

```
if p < 50:
   row[i] = 1
else:
   row[i] = -1
return row
```

right now the only code you are executing 20x is

```
for i in range(0,20):
        p = randint(1,100)
```

row is only being altered once.